# send attributes class via js onclick

Tags: javascript

I use the onclick of javascript to display thumbnails in a specific div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImg(image){
  var imghol = document.getElementById("imageHolder");
  imghol.src = image;
}
</script>
```

...

```
<?php if ($thumb) { ?>
            <div>
                <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" class="zoomE img-responsive" id="imageHolder" data-zoom-image="<?php echo $thumb; ?>"> 
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

I send the image path. How can I send the class and data-zoom-image attributes (elevate zomm plugin)

The idea is to load the image and all its attributes into the Div that receives the image.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can get any attribute with the `getAttribute` function from any HTMLElement

in your case

```
var imghol = document.getElementById("imageHolder");
var myAtt = imghol.getAttribute('someAtt');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass those as params to the `changeImg()` and set it to the element.

```
function changeImg(image, class, dataZoomImage){
  var imghol = document.getElementById("imageHolder");
  imghol.src = image;

  imghol.classList.add(class); // add to classList
  imghol.dataset.zoomImage = dataZoomImage; // set data-zoom-image attribute
}
```

**Docs:**

- [Using data attributes - Learn web development | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)
- [`Element.classList` - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)